# PHP-FPM. Segmentation fault. Don´t understand core dump

Tags: php, segmentation-fault, apache2, internal-server-error

In our web service testing environment, there is one request that causes an 500 internal server error. It occured accidentally for some time. Now the 500 is the result of every request (to one certain REST route).   What we use: Ubuntu Server 12.04, Apache2.2, PHP-FPM (PHP 5.5.16), PHP libs: Zend Framework 2, MongoDB, Doctrine 2 ODM, Redis. Apache was installed via apt. PHP was compiled with config:

```html
./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --datadir=/usr/share/php --mandir=/usr --enable-cli --enable-fastcgi --enable-fpm --with-fpm-user=www-data --with-fpm-group=www-data --with-config-file-path=/etc --without-t1lib --disable-short-tags
--enable-pcntl --with-tsrm-pthreads --with-zlib --enable-sysvmsg --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --enable-bcmath --with-bz2 --enable-calendar --enable-exif --enable-ftp --with-iconv-dir --with-gettext --with-imap --with-imap-ssl --with-openssl --enable-mbstring
--with-mcrypt --with-mhash --with-pspell --enable-soap --enable-sockets --enable-wddx --with-xmlrpc --with-xsl --enable-zip --with-kerberos --with-tidy --with-curl --enable-ctype --enable-dbase --enable-magic-quotes --enable-reflection --enable-exif --with-gd
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr --with-png-dir=/usr --with-vpx-dir=/usr --with-freetype-dir=/usr --with-t1lib --enable-exif --enable-gd-native-ttf --enable-gd-jis-conv --with-pear --enable-debug
```

The only error message we found in apache´s error.log:

```
[Tue Oct 28 13:02:03 2014] [error] [client 172.22.9.6] (104)Connection reset by peer: FastCGI: comm with server "/var/lib/apache2/fastcgi/php5.fastcgi" aborted: read failed
[Tue Oct 28 13:02:03 2014] [error] [client 172.22.9.6] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/var/lib/apache2/fastcgi/php5.fastcgi"
```

No hints in php-fpm.log

kernel.log:

```
    Oct 30 13:05:17 srv42 kernel: [5082178.905310] php-fpm[28668]: segfault at 74ec8319 ip 0000000000a067c9 sp 00007fffae873810 error 4 in php-fpm[400000+bd2000]
Oct 30 13:05:47 srv42 kernel: [5082208.620852] php-fpm[28667]: segfault at 74ec8319 ip 0000000000a067c9 sp 00007fffae873810 error 4 in php-fpm[400000+bd2000]
Oct 30 13:06:28 srv42 kernel: [5082248.973311] php-fpm[28786]: segfault at 74ec8319 ip 0000000000a067c9 sp 00007fffae873810 error 4 in php-fpm[400000+bd2000]
Oct 30 13:07:03 srv42 kernel: [5082284.713304] php-fpm[28784]: segfault at 74ec8319 ip 0000000000a067c9 sp 00007fffae873810 error 4 in php-fpm[400000+bd2000]
Oct 30 13:07:44 srv42 kernel: [5082325.287816] php-fpm[28808]: segfault at 7f3174ec8319 ip 0000000000a067c9 sp 00007fffae873810 error 4 in php-fpm[400000+bd2000]
Oct 30 13:09:25 srv42 kernel: [5082426.089227] php-fpm[28862]: segfault at 74ec8319 ip 0000000000a067c9 sp 00007fffae873810 error 4 in php-fpm[400000+bd2000]
Oct 30 13:13:57 srv42 kernel: [5082698.146905] php-fpm[28861]: segfault at 74ec8319 ip 0000000000a067c9 sp 00007fffae873810 error 4 in php-fpm[400000+bd2000]
Oct 30 13:14:57 srv42 kernel: [5082757.795445] php-fpm[28864]: segfault at 74ec8319 ip 0000000000a067c9 sp 00007fffae873810 error 4 in php-fpm[400000+bd2000]
Oct 30 13:15:08 srv42 kernel: [5082769.605783] php-fpm[28848]: segfault at 74ec8319 ip 0000000000a067c9 sp 00007fffae873810 error 4 in php-fpm[400000+bd2000]
Oct 30 13:15:28 srv42 kernel: [5082788.841189] php-fpm[28878]: segfault at 74ec8319 ip 0000000000a067c9 sp 00007fffae873810 error 4 in php-fpm[400000+bd2000]
Oct 30 13:16:02 srv42 kernel: [5082823.274631] php-fpm[28877]: segfault at 74ec8319 ip 0000000000a067c9 sp 00007fffae873810 error 4 in php-fpm[400000+bd2000]
Oct 30 13:22:04 srv42 kernel: [5083184.891103] php-fpm[28880]: segfault at 74ec8319 ip 0000000000a067c9 sp 00007fffae873810 error 4 in php-fpm[400000+bd2000]
Oct 30 13:22:05 srv42 kernel: [5083186.017818] php-fpm[28875]: segfault at 74ec8319 ip 0000000000a067c9 sp 00007fffae873810 error 4 in php-fpm[400000+bd2000]
Oct 30 13:22:06 srv42 kernel: [5083187.128489] php-fpm[28896]: segfault at 74ec8319 ip 0000000000a067c9 sp 00007fffae873810 error 4 in php-fpm[400000+bd2000]
Oct 30 13:30:25 srv42 kernel: [5083685.280565] php-fpm[28912]: segfault at 74ec8319 ip 0000000000a067c9 sp 00007fffae873810 error 4 in php-fpm[400000+bd2000]
Oct 30 13:46:38 srv42 kernel: [5084658.434006] php-fpm[29418] general protection ip:a067c9 sp:7fffae873810 error:0 in php-fpm[400000+bd2000]
```

Finally, I´ve etxracted the core dump from crash report:

```
root@srv42:/var/php-core-dumps# gdb /usr/sbin/php-fpm /var/php-core-dumps/CoreDump 
GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2.1) 7.4-2012.04
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://bugs.launchpad.net/gdb-linaro/>...
Reading symbols from /usr/sbin/php-fpm...done.
[New LWP 4922]

warning: Can't read pathname for load map: Eingabe-/Ausgabefehler.

warning: .dynamic section for "/usr/lib/php/extensions/debug-non-zts-20121212/mongo.so" is not at the expected address (wrong library or version mismatch?)
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `php-fpm: pool www                                                             '.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x000000000099190a in zend_mm_check_ptr (heap=0x2edf9d0, ptr=0x7f4127407a08, silent=1, __zend_filename=0xf3c1f8 "/home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_hash.c", __zend_lineno=565, __zend_orig_filename=0x0, __zend_orig_lineno=0)
    at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_alloc.c:1384
1384        if (p->info._size != ZEND_MM_NEXT_BLOCK(p)->info._prev) {
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000000099190a in zend_mm_check_ptr (heap=0x2edf9d0, ptr=0x7f4127407a08, silent=1, __zend_filename=0xf3c1f8 "/home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_hash.c", __zend_lineno=565, __zend_orig_filename=0x0, __zend_orig_lineno=0)
    at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_alloc.c:1384
#1  0x0000000000993587 in _zend_mm_free_int (heap=0x2edf9d0, p=0x7f4127407a08, __zend_filename=0xf3c1f8 "/home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_hash.c", __zend_lineno=565, __zend_orig_filename=0x0, __zend_orig_lineno=0) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_alloc.c:2068
#2  0x0000000000994b92 in _efree (ptr=0x7f4127407a08, __zend_filename=0xf3c1f8 "/home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_hash.c", __zend_lineno=565, __zend_orig_filename=0x0, __zend_orig_lineno=0) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_alloc.c:2440
#3  0x00000000009dfa6e in zend_hash_destroy (ht=0xd321bd0) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_hash.c:565
#4  0x00000000009c9feb in _zval_dtor_func (zvalue=0x7f4127407ab0, __zend_filename=0xf38c18 "/home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_execute.h", __zend_lineno=81) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_variables.c:45
#5  0x00000000009b6735 in _zval_dtor (zvalue=0x7f4127407ab0, __zend_filename=0xf38c18 "/home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_execute.h", __zend_lineno=81) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_variables.h:35
#6  0x00000000009b6800 in i_zval_ptr_dtor (zval_ptr=0x7f4127407ab0, __zend_filename=0xf3e5c8 "/home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_objects.c", __zend_lineno=54) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_execute.h:81
#7  0x00000000009b7a2c in _zval_ptr_dtor (zval_ptr=0xd2f5b00, __zend_filename=0xf3e5c8 "/home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_objects.c", __zend_lineno=54) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_execute_API.c:426
#8  0x00000000009fe932 in zend_object_std_dtor (object=0xd321b58) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_objects.c:54
#9  0x00000000009fed5c in zend_objects_free_object_storage (object=0xd321b58) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_objects.c:137
#10 0x0000000000a05ee7 in zend_objects_store_del_ref_by_handle_ex (handle=1025, handlers=0x129cec0) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_objects_API.c:226
#11 0x0000000000a05c30 in zend_objects_store_del_ref (zobject=0xd321ae0) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_objects_API.c:178
#12 0x00000000009ca028 in _zval_dtor_func (zvalue=0xd321ae0, __zend_filename=0xf38c18 "/home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_execute.h", __zend_lineno=81) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_variables.c:54
#13 0x00000000009b6735 in _zval_dtor (zvalue=0xd321ae0, __zend_filename=0xf38c18 "/home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_execute.h", __zend_lineno=81) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_variables.h:35
#14 0x00000000009b6800 in i_zval_ptr_dtor (zval_ptr=0xd321ae0, __zend_filename=0xf3aaa0 "/home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_variables.c", __zend_lineno=182) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_execute.h:81
#15 0x00000000009b7a2c in _zval_ptr_dtor (zval_ptr=0xd3219e0, __zend_filename=0xf3aaa0 "/home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_variables.c", __zend_lineno=182) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_execute_API.c:426
#16 0x00000000009ca43a in _zval_ptr_dtor_wrapper (zval_ptr=0xd3219e0) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_variables.c:182
#17 0x00000000009df9d7 in zend_hash_destroy (ht=0xd3179c8) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_hash.c:560
#18 0x00000000009c9feb in _zval_dtor_func (zvalue=0xd28fbc8, __zend_filename=0xf38c18 "/home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_execute.h", __zend_lineno=81) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_variables.c:45
#19 0x00000000009b6735 in _zval_dtor (zvalue=0xd28fbc8, __zend_filename=0xf38c18 "/home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_execute.h", __zend_lineno=81) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_variables.h:35
#20 0x00000000009b6800 in i_zval_ptr_dtor (zval_ptr=0xd28fbc8, __zend_filename=0xf3aaa0 "/home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_variables.c", __zend_lineno=182) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_execute.h:81
#21 0x00000000009b7a2c in _zval_ptr_dtor (zval_ptr=0xd28f5d8, __zend_filename=0xf3aaa0 "/home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_variables.c", __zend_lineno=182) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_execute_API.c:426
#22 0x00000000009ca43a in _zval_ptr_dtor_wrapper (zval_ptr=0xd28f5d8) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_variables.c:182
#23 0x00000000009df9d7 in zend_hash_destroy (ht=0xd299468) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_hash.c:560
#24 0x00000000009c9feb in _zval_dtor_func (zvalue=0xd281af8, __zend_filename=0xf38c18 "/home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_execute.h", __zend_lineno=81) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_variables.c:45
#25 0x00000000009b6735 in _zval_dtor (zvalue=0xd281af8, __zend_filename=0xf38c18 "/home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_execute.h", __zend_lineno=81) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_variables.h:35
#26 0x00000000009b6800 in i_zval_ptr_dtor (zval_ptr=0xd281af8, __zend_filename=0xf3e5c8 "/home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_objects.c", __zend_lineno=54) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_execute.h:81
#27 0x00000000009b7a2c in _zval_ptr_dtor (zval_ptr=0xd29ba20, __zend_filename=0xf3e5c8 "/home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_objects.c", __zend_lineno=54) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_execute_API.c:426
#28 0x00000000009fe932 in zend_object_std_dtor (object=0xd294040) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_objects.c:54
#29 0x00000000009fed5c in zend_objects_free_object_storage (object=0xd294040) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_objects.c:137
#30 0x0000000000a05ee7 in zend_objects_store_del_ref_by_handle_ex (handle=1009, handlers=0x129cec0) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_objects_API.c:226
#31 0x0000000000a05c30 in zend_objects_store_del_ref (zobject=0xd2946b0) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_objects_API.c:178
#32 0x00000000009ca028 in _zval_dtor_func (zvalue=0xd2946b0, __zend_filename=0xf38c18 "/home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_execute.h", __zend_lineno=81) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_variables.c:54
#33 0x00000000009b6735 in _zval_dtor (zvalue=0xd2946b0, __zend_filename=0xf38c18 "/home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_execute.h", __zend_lineno=81) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_variables.h:35
#34 0x00000000009b6800 in i_zval_ptr_dtor (zval_ptr=0xd2946b0, __zend_filename=0xf3aaa0 "/home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_variables.c", __zend_lineno=182) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_execute.h:81
#35 0x00000000009b7a2c in _zval_ptr_dtor (zval_ptr=0xd24faf8, __zend_filename=0xf3aaa0 "/home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_variables.c", __zend_lineno=182) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_execute_API.c:426
#36 0x00000000009ca43a in _zval_ptr_dtor_wrapper (zval_ptr=0xd24faf8) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_variables.c:182
#37 0x00000000009df9d7 in zend_hash_destroy (ht=0xc8d6f50) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_hash.c:560
#38 0x00000000009c9feb in _zval_dtor_func (zvalue=0xc8ab508, __zend_filename=0xf38c18 "/home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_execute.h", __zend_lineno=81) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_variables.c:45
#39 0x00000000009b6735 in _zval_dtor (zvalue=0xc8ab508, __zend_filename=0xf38c18 "/home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_execute.h", __zend_lineno=81) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_variables.h:35
#40 0x00000000009b6800 in i_zval_ptr_dtor (zval_ptr=0xc8ab508, __zend_filename=0xf3e5c8 "/home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_objects.c", __zend_lineno=54) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_execute.h:81
#41 0x00000000009b7a2c in _zval_ptr_dtor (zval_ptr=0xc2d3a80, __zend_filename=0xf3e5c8 "/home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_objects.c", __zend_lineno=54) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_execute_API.c:426
#42 0x00000000009fe932 in zend_object_std_dtor (object=0xc2884a8) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_objects.c:54
#43 0x00000000009fed5c in zend_objects_free_object_storage (object=0xc2884a8) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_objects.c:137
#44 0x0000000000a05ee7 in zend_objects_store_del_ref_by_handle_ex (handle=188, handlers=0x129cec0) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_objects_API.c:226
#45 0x0000000000a05c30 in zend_objects_store_del_ref (zobject=0xc284410) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_objects_API.c:178
#46 0x00000000009ca028 in _zval_dtor_func (zvalue=0xc284410, __zend_filename=0xf38c18 "/home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_execute.h", __zend_lineno=81) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_variables.c:54
#47 0x00000000009b6735 in _zval_dtor (zvalue=0xc284410, __zend_filename=0xf38c18 "/home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_execute.h", __zend_lineno=81) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_variables.h:35
#48 0x00000000009b6800 in i_zval_ptr_dtor (zval_ptr=0xc284410, __zend_filename=0xf3e5c8 "/home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_objects.c", __zend_lineno=54) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_execute.h:81
#49 0x00000000009b7a2c in _zval_ptr_dtor (zval_ptr=0xbfc4ee0, __zend_filename=0xf3e5c8 "/home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_objects.c", __zend_lineno=54) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_execute_API.c:426
#50 0x00000000009fe932 in zend_object_std_dtor (object=0xc280918) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_objects.c:54
#51 0x00000000009fed5c in zend_objects_free_object_storage (object=0xc280918) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_objects.c:137
#52 0x0000000000a05ee7 in zend_objects_store_del_ref_by_handle_ex (handle=177, handlers=0x129cec0) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_objects_API.c:226
#53 0x0000000000a05c30 in zend_objects_store_del_ref (zobject=0xc2800e8) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_objects_API.c:178
#54 0x00000000009ca028 in _zval_dtor_func (zvalue=0xc2800e8, __zend_filename=0xf38c18 "/home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_execute.h", __zend_lineno=81) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_variables.c:54
#55 0x00000000009b6735 in _zval_dtor (zvalue=0xc2800e8, __zend_filename=0xf38c18 "/home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_execute.h", __zend_lineno=81) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_variables.h:35
#56 0x00000000009b6800 in i_zval_ptr_dtor (zval_ptr=0xc2800e8, __zend_filename=0xf3e5c8 "/home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_objects.c", __zend_lineno=54) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_execute.h:81
#57 0x00000000009b7a2c in _zval_ptr_dtor (zval_ptr=0xc26cf88, __zend_filename=0xf3e5c8 "/home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_objects.c", __zend_lineno=54) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_execute_API.c:426
#58 0x00000000009fe932 in zend_object_std_dtor (object=0xc26cee0) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_objects.c:54
#59 0x00000000009fed5c in zend_objects_free_object_storage (object=0xc26cee0) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_objects.c:137
#60 0x0000000000a05963 in zend_objects_store_free_object_storage (objects=0x12c1120) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_objects_API.c:97
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#61 0x00000000009b7514 in shutdown_executor () at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend_execute_API.c:293
#62 0x00000000009cc5d0 in zend_deactivate () at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/Zend/zend.c:935
#63 0x000000000093419b in php_request_shutdown (dummy=0x0) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/main/main.c:1808
#64 0x0000000000a88fa7 in main (argc=6, argv=0x7fff143861e8) at /home/root/src/php-5.5.16/sapi/fpm/fpm/fpm_main.c:1961
```

The "/home/root/src...." is the path, where i´ve extracted PHP´s source code.

This dump doesn´t look like the ones I´ve seen in some tutorials. I don´t get the real reason why the requests causes this error, or PHP is killed:

- Is it because used memory is released, some weird memory addresses, PHP bug?
- error in hash functions?
- ...

And what does these warnings mean? Especially the mongo.so warning? Mongo was installed/updated via PECL. So why should the version be wrong or why shouldn´t it be placed in the right extension folder of PHP.

Thanks for any help and advice.

Edit:
If OPcache v7.0.4-dev extension is enabled, the error doesn´t occure.

Comment: if php is crashing with a segfault, then you've got a major issue. there's no way that php code should cause the php interpreter to crash.

Comment: Thanks. So, a quick solution would be an update of PHP? Any other advice?

Comment: FWIW there are lots of things you can do in regular PHP code to cause a segfault. For example, too much recursion will cause a segfault. https://bitdepth.thomasrutter.com/2010/05/16/php-recursion-causes-segmentation-fault/